# Unknown operator [colon] used with while loop java

Tags: java, operators

while browsing some source code i noticed a weird operator being used on a while loop

`topLoop: while(dist < 0){
  random code...
}`

what does the 'topLoop:' mean in this situation? and what does it do to the while exactly?
p.s. topLoop is just a int defined earlier on in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colon is not an operator. The `topLoop:` is called a [label](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). You can use it, for example, to directly jump from a nested loop to outside the outer loop.

There's probably a `break topLoop;` statement somewhere inside the loop that you didn't show. This will make execution jump to the `topLoop` label.

Labels are used only seldomly in practice, and in my opinion using labels is bad practice - they are a kind of [goto statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto), and using them can quickly make your code a hard to understand, [tangled mess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

> p.s. topLoop is just a int defined earlier on in the code.

Maybe the code has a variable named `topLoop`, but this has nothing to do with the label that happens to have the same name.

Comment: ah thank you very much that makes a lot of scene now